# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer for search with geokit-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, geocoding, geokit

I've got the geokit-rails gem installed with geocoder, and have loaded my configuration correctly with the right API keys and settings. I've properly constructed ActiveRecord objects that have encoded `lat` and `lng` columns with float values. Now I am trying to simply search for venues (Venue activerecord) that are within 100km of the given origin as so:

```
Venue.within(100, origin: Geokit::LatLng.new(-27.12,124.2141))
```

Yet I keep receiving the error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.3/lib/geocoder/sql.rb:14:in `[]'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.3/lib/geocoder/sql.rb:14:in `full_distance'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/geocoder-1.2.3/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb:157:in `distance_sql'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/geokit-rails-2.0.1/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:228:in `distance_conditions'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/geokit-rails-2.0.1/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:108:in `within'
    from (irb):46
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Would someone help?

Comment: Geokit/geokit-rails aren't meant to be used together. You may wish to try only using 1 if that is possible. May I ask why you are using both?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelNoack I can't exactly remember why I used both, but that is a likely cause of the problem. I'll try and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant geocoder and geokit aren't meant to be used together. geokit-rails requires geokit so they are meant used together :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Geokit within method with Lat&Long directly - [from docs](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails).
F.e: 
    `:origin => [37.792,-122.393].`
In your case `Venue.within(100, origin: [-27.12,124.2141])`

Why do you use Geokit::LatLng.new for this?

Comment: I use it to make the code clear, but I have tried this already and it does not solve the problem.